# Cascading drop down list (SubLocality) not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

**I have three dropdown List.The First action method for City drop down is as---**

```
            public ActionResult Create()
            {
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select your City", Value = "----" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Faridabaad", Value = "Faridabaad" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Greater Noida", Value = "Greater Noida" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Gurgaon", Value = "Gurgaon" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Noida", Value = "Noida" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "New Delhi", Value = "New Delhi" });
        ViewData["City"] = li;
        return View();
    }
```

**then i have action method for my Locality drop down list which changes as we change city name like this------**

```
        public JsonResult LoadLocalities(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> localities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        switch(id)
        {
      case"New Delhi":
         localities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select your locality", Value = "0" });
                localities.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text ="East Delhi", Value = "1" });
                    localities.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text ="West Delhi", Value = "2" });
                        localities.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text ="North Delhi", Value = "3" });
                        localities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "South Delhi", Value = "4" });
                        break;           
        }
        return Json(new SelectList(localities, "Value", "Text"));
    }
```

**and the action method for the last sub locality drop down which changes with the change in locality name is like this---**

```
      public JsonResult LoadSubLocalities(string id)
       {
        List<SelectListItem> sublocalities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        switch (id)
        {
            case"1":
                sublocalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select your sublocality", Value = "0" });
                sublocalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Region1", Value = "1" });
                sublocalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Region2", Value = "2" });
                break;
        }
        return Json(new SelectList(sublocalities, "Value", "Text"));
    }
```

**now the view page is something like this------**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
        <title></title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>   
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 700px; float:left"></div>
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter the Project Details</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("City")){
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, ViewData["City"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { style = "width:250px", @class = "DropDown1"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
            }
    </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Locality)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Locality", new SelectList(string.Empty,"Value","Text"),"Please Select a locality", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "DropDown1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Locality)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubLocality)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("SubLocality", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select a sub locality", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "DropDown1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubLocality)
        </div>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Project" />
           </p>
           </fieldset>
```

**Now my javaScript code is something like this where i have written code to fetch city from controller then change locality as the city name changes and change sub locality name with change in locality name-----**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#City").change(function () {
            $("#Locality").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadLocalities","Project")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#City").val() },
                success: function (localities) {
                    $.each(localities, function (i, locality) {
                        $("#Locality").append('<option value="' + locality.Value + '">' +
                             locality.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retreive Locality.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
                $("#Locality").change(function () {
                $("#SubLocality").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("LoadSubLocalities")',
                    dataType: 'Json',
                    data: { id: $("Locality").val() },
                    success: function (sublocalities) {
                        $.each(sublocalities, function (i, sublocality) {
                            $("#SubLocality").append('<option value="' + sublocality.Value + '">' +
                                 sublocality.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve SubLocality.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
            });
         </script>
       }
```

**Now, My problem is that my Locality is working fine with change in city name but SubLocality drop down is not working with change in locality name---**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `$("#Locality").change(function () {` is not working is because the following line

```
data: { id: $("Locality").val() },
```

return `undefined`. It needs to be

```
data: { id: $("#Locality").val() }, // add hash
```

however the correct approach is to use

```
data: { id: $(this).val() },
```

in order to avoid traversing the DOM again to get the element with `id="Locality"`

There are numerous other issues with your code, particularly in respect to validation and returning the view if `ModelState` is invalid

1. When generating `List<SelectListItem>`, do not add the label option
   (i.e. `sublocalities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select your
   sublocality", Value = "0" });`). You are giving the label option a
   value which means that its always valid. As it currently is, you may
   as well delete the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` associated with
   each dropdown.
2. Never give the `SelectList` the same name as the property your
   binding to (in your case `City`)
3. In your `LoadLocalities()` and `LoadSubLocalities()` methods you
   first create `List<SelectListItem>` and then create a new
   `SelectList` (which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) so its just
   unnecessary extra overhead. In any case the client has no knowledge
   of what a C# class is and you just returning twice as much data
   across the wire as is necessary (the `Selected`,`Disabled` and
   `Group` properties which you never use). Instead just pass back a
   collection of anonymous objects containing 2 properties (for the
   option value and text)

Comment: Thank you very much @StephenMuecke for fixing the code with some  valuable advice.....

Comment: @AshishSrivastava, I have updated the fiddle to include a typical POST method and modified the `private void ConfigureViewModel(ViewModel model)` to show how to handle returning the view if `ModelState` is invalid

Comment: yupp I have seen that too.Lots of thanks for your Effort Sir to guide me out of the box......would love to have guidance from you Sir in near future too....thnxxx a lot once again